# Unable to resolve the request in Yii

Tags: yii

I have a model colled InvoiceItem and BankAccoun, their database table called: tbl_invoice_item and tbl_bank_account.

So when I was working on my local server it was working fine but when I uploaded to internet I got error:

Error 404
Unable to resolve the request "InvoiceItem".
I did not changed any think and the InvoiceItem model and controller are still there.

Any help please ?

Comment: did you name for case sensitive?

Comment: Judging by your question I'd say look for a typo.

Comment: You might have case sensitive issues Windows vs. Linux. Look for a typo.

Comment: Please how to check typo ??

Comment: @MahdiMiad grep "invoiceitem" or "Invoiceitem" or "invoiceItem"